# Check if array1 has any same numbers as array2

Tags: c#

I have a school assignment where we are making a bingo game. But I am stuck on one thing.
I want to check if array1 contains any numbers of array2, no matter the position of those numbers.
Array1 is supposed to be filled with 10 numbers from the user and array2 is supposed to be 10 random numbers between 1-21.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing two arrays in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052132/comparing-two-arrays-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Should it take into an account duplicates? Can you please share your attempt?

Comment: You did ask the same question and I provided an answer. Please don't tell us to use a single dimension array this time.

Comment: Sorry guys i am new to programming and this forum i dont understand anything

Answer (score 0):

```
bool MatchAny(int[] array1, int[] array2)
{
    for(int i=0;i<array1.Length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<array2.Length;j++)
        {
            if(array1[i]==array2[j]) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

EDIT: If you want it to instead return an array with all the matches:

```
//using System;
//using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Linq;

int[] MatchAny(int[] array1, int[] array2)
{
    List<int> matched=new int[0].ToList();
    for(int i=0;i<array1.Length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<array2.Length;j++)
        {
            if(matched.Contains(array1[i])) continue;
            //Comment out the previous line to allow duplicates
            if(array1[i]==array2[j]) matched.Add(array1[i]);
        }
    }
    return matched.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Do you know anyway to like print out those numbers that matched?

Comment: But, that's not what you asked. If that's what you want, you'll need to change `bool MatchAny` to `void ShowMatches` (same params), and change the body of the function so that instead of returning `true` on the first match, you output the matching number on each match. If you still want to tell if there was a match or not, you'll need a local Boolean flag (initialized to `false` that you set to `true` if a match is found